# using Node.js' https.request() and outputting to a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, https

Im following a article about http requests to nasa's pic of the day. I'm trying to display the JSON object in browser from my server. But all Node.js' examples outputs the api results to a server's console. is it possible to have my server save/forward the response to the browser? I'd like to understand the native http module before relying on any dependencies. Also I'm not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using express to create my server. anything will help even a high level explanation because I'm so confused.

```
const https = require('https');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY';
  var nasa_obj
  var request = https.get(url, function (resp) {
    var body = '';

    resp.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', function () {
      nasa_obj = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log("Got a response: ", nasa_obj);
      res.send(nasa_obj)
    });
  }).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Got an error: ", e);
  });
  request.end()
})
```

UPDATED: CODE IS CORRECT

Comment: Do you have an actual HTTP server running in your code? Also, `nasa_obj` is undefined until `res.on('end')` resolves. Move `res.send` up to that event listener.

Comment: ah yes I got it working, it makes sense now sometimes scope can be so confusing haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only want to send the response once it has been returned to you:

```js
const https = require('https');

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  var url = 'https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY';
  var nasa_obj
  var request = https.get(url, function (response) {
    var body = '';

    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', function () {
      console.log("Got a response: ", body);
      res.send(body);
    });
  }).on('error', function (e) {
    console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    next(e); // Pass error to error handling middleware
  });
  request.end()
})
```

Also make sure you are properly handling errors. Either send back a response to the browser to, as the code above is doing, pass it on to error handling middleware.